# Possible issue with gold badge dupehammer

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, badges

Earler, a few folks with gold badges were attempting to mark
https://stackoverflow.com/q/30402343/3005513 as a duplicate of [retrieve Y value from density function of given X value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24957905/3005513). However, whenever they did so, the post would get erroneously marked as a duplicate of [Am I able to run SQL functions on a ContentResolver columns query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495657/am-i-able-to-run-sql-functions-on-a-contentresolver-columns-query), which is in absolutely no way relevent. Two different users attempted this with the same result. You can see it in the revision history for the question.

I raised a mod flag and Brad Larson stepped in. He was able to successfully mark the question with its appropriate duplicate. He recommended I mention this issue here as it may be a bug with the golden dupehammer.

Has anyone else observed this behavior? Is it indeed a bug?

Comment: It is hard for us non mods to see what really happened here. To someone who did not view this happening live, it looks like both users simply placed the wrong url in the duplicate popout selector. I looked at the revision history and the timeline and neither offered any evidence of previous close votes (which may have been present). Hopefully someone on the team can look at this to see if something actually went wrong or if it was simply an honest mistake with two users.

Comment: @TravisJ: That would be a very strange coincidence for them both to mark it as duplicate with the same irrelevant URL, but not impossible. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Looking at the comment he posted, this is the actual URL he was trying to use to close the question:

```
/questions/24957905/retrieve-y-value-from-density-function-of-given-x-value/2495800
```

Notice the number on the end there? That happens to be the ID number for the *answer* to this question:

[Am I able to run SQL functions on a ContentResolver columns query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495657/am-i-able-to-run-sql-functions-on-a-contentresolver-columns-query/2495800#2495800)

So the system was picking up the second ID number rather than the first. Normally that number would not cause harm because it's meant to indicate an answer *on that question*, so whether it looks up the question ID or answer ID, the duplicate would end up in the same place. When they don't match, well that's just weird.

Looking at the *intended* duplicate target, the answer ID there is 24958001 ← with a "1" on the end of it. So somewhere along the line characters got deleted and changed the URL to something it's not supposed to be, resulting in oddness.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info, animuson. There's a reason why people elect folks like you to become mods. :)

Comment: @AlexA.animuson is a Stack Exchange employee now. So he wasn't only elected a mod, he also got hired. :)

Comment: Does it mean a bug in the site engine (a trailing character is stripped unnecessarily)? Or is it just a coincidence that two users have managed to delete the last character independently?

Comment: @JFSebastian The second user likely copy-pasted the already-bad link when attempting to close. I found that link in a deleted comment which stated that was the intended target. The link takes you to the correct place when entered into the address bar, but not in the duplicate search.